# React-native trigger/simulate touch on screen by given x, y coordinates

Tags: react-native, coordinates, touch-event

I would like to have a button in the react-native app so that can trigger/simulate a touch on the screen by giving x, and y coordinates. Just like:

touchMe(x, y)

Is there any way that can help me to do that?

I have read some articles about mock touch by using jest, and enzyme but they are used for testing. Do they use it for development as well?

Please help to advise!

Thank you!

Comment: reason? If it is to simply trigger an `onPress()`, you could have this function be called somewhere else

Comment: I just want to make a button for tutorial when visit the page. A drag-able button, then touch, then touch on that button means user touch on the position of the view under the button

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @Boomba ?

Comment: no solution yet . . . ?

Comment: anything . . . ?